# How to fetch or select new data from any database?

Tags: mongodb

I am creating an automated process to convert Json data into csv file. I am getting Json from Mongo Db. The process start once at 24 Hrs. In this process the json is converted into csv file and that csv file is stored with the current date as a name. **Like 2018-03-21.csv**. The collection inside db is updating continuously. So, if a process is started on the next day then whole collection element will be converted that takes lots of time.

And yes my task is to create a csv on the daily basis data.

So my question is is there any way or query to select only newly added data ?

Comment: Are you storing the timestamps whenever a new entry is created in your database?

Comment: No there is no time stamp but there is a field when the user has created(registered). I am also thinking to consider it is it the proper way ? That field is storing date into ISO form

Comment: If you know when the data entry is made, then you can use that field to fetch only the newly created data from your database when you are extracting the JSON.

Comment: OK, but just consider a scenario, I new user is registered today that is 21-03-2018 and we stored his data into csv. Then on the next day he make some changes and the update column has new date i.e.22-03-2018 then in this situation how can I counter the duplicate data .

Comment: Ok. I recommended you store the created-at and updated-at timestamps in separate fields.

Comment: If you cannot change the existing schema, then maybe you can consider making use of the user id for fetching the newly created data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even you don't have "created_at" (or similar) field at your collection, you probably have ObjectId() at your _id field... [First four bytes of that ObjectId is timestamp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) (unix; seconds from epoc) of document creation. So, you make query like `db.collection.find({"_id":{$gt:ObjectId(<timestamp_as_hex>+"00000000")}})`